# Integrate app with active directory Light Service

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Now I am trying to build a .net app(C#), I trying to integrate my app with windows active directory to authenticate user and password in AD, since its still in development.

So, I decided to use Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services as substitute of AD, but the problem is my PC does not have any domain, it's a local computer.

I really have no idea what I am going to put in my connection string. can anyone help me? and put some examples pls, thank you. any help will be great.. by the way my PC using windows 7, and I am using .net 4.5 / MS VS 2012.

Here is some of my code

C# :

```
string connection =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnection"].ToString();
DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher(connection);
dssearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + txtusername.Text + ")";
SearchResult sresult = dssearch.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry dsresult = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry();
lblfname.Text = dsresult.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
lbllname.Text = dsresult.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
lblemail.Text = dsresult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: I would recommend downloading VirtualBox and creating a Virtual Computer to do your development on. Then you can add it to a domain and mess around with the settings without affecting your actual computer.

Comment: hello, sorry for late reply, thank you for your suggestion, but i am kinda new to VirtualBox thing, actually i never use it, can you guide me how to use it? thank you.

Comment: It's relatively simple and a quick google search would find you a guide which will explain in far more in depth, with pictures etcetera, than I have to time to do.

Answer (score 0):

AD LDS (Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services) is different from a full-blown Active Directory. Active Directory consists of:

1. A database, accessible via LDAP
2. A database schema which uses the database to store accounts, groups and other stuff
3. An authentication service that uses the above to authenticate accounts.

AD LDS is just the database - no accounts, groups or authentication service. You're supposed to extend its schema to accommodate the stuff you want to store in it.

So, you can't use AD LDS for user authentication. I join the recommendation of setting up a test computer (possibly a virtual machine), configuring it as a Domain Controller, and testing on it.

Comment: thank you for your enlightenment Jonathan, now i have a better understanding about AD LDS, so we can say that it is impossible to use AD LDS for authenticate users without our computer joining a domain, right?